# jQuery making a whole Div a clickable link with _blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I am trying to create a whole Div clickable and link to anew tab. So far I have made the div clickable and send to a new link with this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.wish-list').click(function(){
          location.href = 'https://link.com'
    })
  });
```

This works sending the page you are on to the link but I would like to do the same action but opening a new tab.

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: use ``window.location.href = "http://link.com";``

Comment: @RakeshRaj hey thanks for that, but that is still just opening the link in the same window, I am trying to open it in a new tab, trying to create the "target = _blank" event

Comment: use this ``window.open('https://link.com', '_blank');``

Answer (score 3):

You can use [window.open](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp):

```
window.open("http://link.com", "_blank");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
window.open('url', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 1):

[window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

use this instead of location.href

```
window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);
```

Example

```
window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');
```

Comment: `_blank` is not needed as the second parameter to `window.open()`. As long as a `width` or a `height` are not set, the window will open full size (a new tab).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `window.open()`. The snippet below won't work in the Stack Overflow snippet environment due to sandboxing, but you can see it work **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lw99j9ja/9/)**:

```js
$(function(){
   $('.link').on("click", function(){
     window.open(this.dataset.url);
   });
});
```

```css
.link {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link" data-URL="http://espn.com">ESPN</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 window.open('url', '_blank');
```